# How to save meta value from custom form to Woocommere order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I defined those two functions which should save form value to session variable.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_custom_data_vase', 10, 2 );
function add_cart_item_custom_data_vase( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $cart_item_meta['colour'] = $_POST['colour'][$product_id];
  return $cart_item_meta; 
}

function get_cart_items_from_session( $item, $values, $key ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'colour', $values ) )
        $item[ 'colour' ] = $values['colour'];
    return $item;   
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'get_cart_items_from_session', 1, 3 );
```

But I don't know how to save that value to Woocommerce order as a meta of item. I tried it the way bellow but my value (colour) didn't show in items and also not in $_SESSION or $_COOKIE.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_my_meta', 1, 1);

function add_my_meta($order_id) {
   $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
   $items = $order->get_items(); /* this doesn't include colour item */
   foreach($items as $idx => $val){
       wc_update_order_item_meta( $idx, "colour",$what_variable); // here is my problem, what value use instead of $what_variable?
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a little bit more about what you are trying to achieve exactly? Am I right that you are trying to update an order using custom checkout fields after an order has gone through? If that's the case, there are probably better hooks that I could direct you toward. If you do need the trigger to be only on the Thank You page then you might still be better off using a hook that fires during checkout to ensure that all the data is both processed and available when you need it on the Thank You page.

Comment: I just want to add my custom value to order and actually I don't care if it will be before or after creating order. The best option will be use variable product but I in this case I would need to create grouped prodct of variable products which is almost impossible in Woocommerce so I am trying it througt form data but some Woocommerce hooks doesn't have documentation - especially when they come classes.

Comment: I think you probably want to target the function where WooCommerce actually makes an order based on the cart at checkout. The most likely candidate for this is the `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` action that's called in WC_Checkout::create_order(). It passes in what I think is all the data you need: the line-item ID, the product object, and a cart item key (which I don't think you need). This will get called for each line item during checkout, so you can simply update it right when it's created - no session data to keep track of.

Comment: Than you I made my final solutution based on that action.